# How to make use of conda environment's GCC 7.5.0?

Tags: python, gcc, anaconda, conda

My default version of gcc is gcc 4.8.5:

```
which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

$ /usr/bin/gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
...
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC)
```

After I installed conda with python 3.8 and found that gcc comes with python3.8, which is 7.5.0 as below in my conda environment:

```
$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  4 2021, 15:09:15) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

How can I use gcc 7.5.0 in this conda environment instead of the default system gcc 4.8.5? I can't find the gcc executable under conda. I am compiling a cython project but it complains that it can't find cython as below (I already did: conda install cython):

```
/data0/spacy/vocab.pxd:3:0: 'preshed/maps.pxd' not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data0/bin/cythonize.py", line 59, in process_pyx
    r = subprocess.call(
  File "/usr/home/congmin/.conda/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 340, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/home/congmin/.conda/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/home/congmin/.conda/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1704, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cython'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

I suspect if I get conda environment use gcc 7.5.0, I may fix the cython error.

Comment: How to install gcc 7.5.0 in Conda?

Comment: I think you're confusing the compiler used to compile an executable with what's installed in the system. Whoever packaged anaconda used gcc 7.5.0 to build anaconda, but that doesn't mean it includes the compiler in the binary. It's akin to saying "made in Japan" means Japan must be in my product.

Comment: @BenY I am still confused. How to use conda environment with non-default gcc, such as gcc 7.5.0? I should install it in my conda environemnt, right?

Comment: A compiler takes source code, converts it in to machine language, then produces the binary executable. As a hint for those who may want to debug any issues with this compiled program, the version of the compiler is noted. The compiler used is a tool for whoever made the executable that you have downloaded. You will have to install this tool kit yourself if you want to use the exact same thing. When one distributes a product, they don't also distribute all the tools used in making it. That's like thinking that the factory that made your car was included as part of your car.

Comment: @BenY I got a cython not found error message when compiling a cython project. So you mean probably this has nothing to do with the version of GCC?

Comment: If the compiler can build a binary for your system, the version should not matter. I just set up an empty virtual environment and installed cython as the only package. When I typed `cython` on my shell, it gave me a long usage message. I do not use anaconda, but if it is properly installed in your environment, there should be a command `cython` available from your shell. I was also able to invoke `import cython` from within a Python shell.

Comment: It looks as if you are trying to compile spacy on linux. On the spacy website it says: "Install system-level dependencies via apt-get: sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev git." Have you tried this?

Comment: @fotisj   I am on CentOs, not Ubuntu. Ubunto is fine. Yes, it's spacy.

Comment: Have you seen [this issue on the feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/cython-feedstock/issues/76)? Maintainers recommend also installing the `conda-forge::compilers` package for local building with `cython`. Maybe not so relevant, but I use that package for C++ compilation on local source, just not Cython.